# Define hoverinfo in htmlwidgets/plotly object from sendCustomMessage()

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, htmlwidgets

I have a Shiny application where I create an interactive scatterplot made of hexagons. If the user hovers over a hexagon, a hover will indicate how many points are in that data ("count: x").

I am now trying to send a list variable called "points" through the sendCustomMessage() function in Shiny. One item in this list is called "plotID". This is a character array that contains 60 ID values ("ID4", "ID68", etc).

The "points" object seems to successfully transfer into the htmlwidgets plotlyHex() object through the Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler() function. Using Chrome DevTools and the command console.log(drawPoints.plotID), I can verify that the "plotID" object becomes an array of characters in the browser. I am now trying to set this as the hoverinfo item in htmlwidgets so that when a user clicks on "Add points!" button, these 60 points will be drawn as pink dots and the user can hover over each one to obtain their ID name.

I tried to accomplish this with the hoverinfo: drawPoints.plotID command in my working example below, but this does not seem to help. Indeed, in the current code, the user can hover over the pink points, but what they see is the x coordinate, y coordinate, and some arbitrary trace value.

How can I tweak the below code so that the user will see the ID upon hovering over the superimposed pink points? Thanks for any suggestions!

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(utils)
library(tidyr)
library(stats)
library(hexbin)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(shinycssloaders)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinycssloaders)
library(Hmisc)
library(RColorBrewer)

options(spinner.color.background="#F5F5F5")
pointColor = colList = scales::seq_gradient_pal("maroon1", "maroon4", "Lab")(seq(0,1,length.out=8))[1]

dat = data.frame(ID = paste0("ID", 1:5000), A.1 = round(abs(rnorm(5000,100,70))), A.2 = round(abs(rnorm(5000,100,70))), A.3 = round(abs(rnorm(5000,100,70))), B.1 = round(abs(rnorm(5000,100,70))), B.2 = round(abs(rnorm(5000,100,70))), B.3 = round(abs(rnorm(5000,100,70))))
dat$ID = as.character(dat$ID)

dataMetrics = data.frame(ID = paste0("ID", 1:5000), logFC = rnorm(5000,0,10), PValue = runif(5000, 0, 1))

datCol <- colnames(dat)[-which(colnames(dat) %in% "ID")]
myPairs <- unique(sapply(datCol, function(x) unlist(strsplit(x,"[.]"))[1]))
myMetrics <- colnames(dataMetrics[[1]])[-which(colnames(dataMetrics[[1]]) %in% "ID")]

sidebar <- shinydashboard::dashboardSidebar(
  shinydashboard::sidebarMenu(id="tabs", shinydashboard::menuItem("Example", tabName="exPlot")
  )
)

body <- shinydashboard::dashboardBody(
shinydashboard::tabItems(
shinydashboard::tabItem(tabName = "exPlot",
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 4, 
      shinydashboard::box(width = NULL, status = "primary", title = "Add points", solidHeader = TRUE, 
      shiny::actionButton("goButton", "Add points!"))),
column(width = 8,
    shinydashboard::box(width = NULL, shinycssloaders::withSpinner(plotly::plotlyOutput("exPlot")), collapsible = FALSE, background = "black", title = "Example plot", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE))))))

ui <- shinydashboard::dashboardPage(
  shinydashboard::dashboardHeader(title = "Example", titleWidth = 180),
  sidebar,
  body
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  fcInputMax = max(dataMetrics[["logFC"]])

  curPairSel <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {
  dataMetrics[which(dataMetrics[["PValue"]] < 0.05 & dataMetrics[["logFC"]] > 6),]})

  output$exPlot <- plotly::renderPlotly({

    xMax = max(dataMetrics[["logFC"]])
    xMin = min(dataMetrics[["logFC"]])
    yMax = -log(min(dataMetrics[["PValue"]]))
    yMin = -log(max(dataMetrics[["PValue"]]))
    fcMax = ceiling(max(exp(xMax), 1/exp(xMin)))

    x = dataMetrics[["logFC"]]
    y = -log(dataMetrics[["PValue"]])
    h = hexbin(x=x, y=y, xbins=10, shape=3, IDs=TRUE, xbnds=c(xMin, xMax), ybnds=c(yMin, yMax))
    hexdf = data.frame (hcell2xy (h),  hexID = h@cell, counts = h@count)
    attr(hexdf, "cID") <- h@cID

    # By default, groups into six equal-sized bins
    hexdf$countColor <- cut2(hexdf$counts, g=6, oneval=FALSE)
    hexdf$countColor2 <- as.factor(unlist(lapply(as.character(hexdf$countColor), function(x) substring(strsplit(gsub(" ", "", x, fixed = TRUE), ",")[[1]][1], 2))))
    hexdf$countColor2 <- factor(hexdf$countColor2, levels = as.character(sort(as.numeric(levels(hexdf$countColor2)))))

    for (i in 1:(length(levels(hexdf$countColor2))-1)){
      levels(hexdf$countColor2)[i] <- paste0(levels(hexdf$countColor2)[i],"-",levels(hexdf$countColor2)[i+1])
    }
    levels(hexdf$countColor2)[length(levels(hexdf$countColor2))] <- paste0(levels(hexdf$countColor2)[length(levels(hexdf$countColor2))], "+")

    my_breaks = levels(hexdf$countColor2)
    clrs <- brewer.pal(length(my_breaks)+3, "Purples")
    clrs <- clrs[3:length(clrs)]

    p <- reactive(ggplot2::ggplot(hexdf, aes(x=x, y=y, hexID=hexID, counts=counts, fill=countColor2)) + geom_hex(stat="identity") + scale_fill_manual(labels = as.character(my_breaks), values = rev(clrs), name = "Count") + theme(axis.text=element_text(size=15), axis.title=element_text(size=15), legend.title=element_text(size=15), legend.text=element_text(size=15)) + coord_cartesian(xlim = c(xMin, xMax), ylim = c(yMin, yMax)) + xlab("logFC") + ylab(paste0("-log10(", "PValue", ")")))

    gP <- eventReactive(p(), {
      gP <- plotly::ggplotly(p(), height = 400)
      for (i in 1:(length(gP$x$data)-1)){
        info <- gP$x$data[i][[1]]$text
        info2 <- strsplit(info,"[<br/>]")
        myIndex <- which(startsWith(info2[[1]], "counts:"))
        gP$x$data[i][[1]]$text <- info2[[1]][myIndex]
      }
      gP$x$data[length(gP$x$data)][[1]]$text <- NULL
      gP
    })

    plotlyHex <- reactive(gP() %>% config(displayModeBar = F))

    # Use onRender() function to draw x and y values of selected rows as orange point
    plotlyHex() %>% onRender("
       function(el, x, data) {
       Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('points', function(drawPoints) {
console.log(drawPoints.plotID)
       var Traces = [];
       var trace = {
       x: drawPoints.plotX,
       y: drawPoints.plotY,
       hoverinfo: drawPoints.plotID,
       mode: 'markers',
       marker: {
       color: '#FF34B3',
       size: drawPoints.pointSize,
       },
       showlegend: false
       };
       Traces.push(trace);
       Plotly.addTraces(el.id, Traces);
       });}")
  })

  observe({

    plotX <- curPairSel()[["logFC"]]
    plotY <- -log(curPairSel()[["PValue"]])
    plotID <- curPairSel()[["ID"]]
    pointSize <- 8

    # Send x and y values of selected row into onRender() function
    session$sendCustomMessage(type = "points", message=list(plotX=plotX, plotY=plotY, plotID=plotID, pointSize = pointSize))
  })

  }  

shiny::shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a 3D plot that has some hover info, and my call to hover looks like this:

```
hoverinfo = 'text',
text = ~paste(
'</br> Time(sec): ', T,
'</br> Directly Measured Volume: ', X,
'</br> Flow: ', Y,
'</br> CO2: ', Z),
```

Where the ' strings:' are all text displayed on the hover box immediately prior to the variables within the data frame named T,X,Y and Z.

In your case I think we are talking about this:

```
hoverinfo: 'text',
text = ~paste(
'</br> ID: ', drawPoints.plotID),
```

Try that and let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I tried this idea in several ways but am unsuccessful so far. For instance, I tried exactly as you suggested, but I also tried: Changing the assignment operators : and = in different ways, switching the order of the two commands, defining the text variable after creating the Traces variable but before creating the traces variable, etc. What happens in all these cases is the pink points no longer plot. I tried both RStudio and web browsers (Chrome). Were your data frame T,X,Y, and Z variable also passed in to the onRender() function through sendCustomMessage?

Comment: This answer is in R, but you could do the same thing in JS like `var trace = { hoverinfo: 'text', text: drawPoints.plotID }`

Comment: @gregL: Thank you, that works! And I did not realize Michael's recommendation was for in R not JS. Your answer made me realize I simply needed to convert my original JS code `hoverinfo: drawPoints.plotID` into the two separate chunks you listed.